# RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1, I get this error everytime i reload my screen

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the entire code of the page, whenever I reload the page I get this error for a few seconds and then it disappears. I know the code is very messy and I am sorry for that but this problem just keeps on coming again and again.

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:space_flight_recorder/nav_bar/Nav_Drawer.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:space_flight_recorder/nav_bar/bottom_nav_bar.dart';


class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomeState createState() => _MyHomeState();
}

class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  DateTime launchTime = DateTime.now();
  String Name='';
  String description='';
  String agencyName='';
  String type = '';
  String rocketName='';
  String rocketVariant='';
  String missionName='';
  String orbitName='';
  String location='';
  String time='';
  String date = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchMyHome();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => updateCountdown());

  }

  void fetchMyHome() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.2.0/launch/upcoming/')
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final List<dynamic> results = data['results'];
      if (results.isNotEmpty) {
        final launch = results.elementAt(0);
        final launchTimeStr = launch['net'];
        launchTime = DateTime.parse(launchTimeStr).toLocal();
        final Launchname = launch['name'];
        Name = Launchname.toString();
        final descp = launch['mission']['description'];
        description=descp;
        final agenName=launch['launch_service_provider']['name'];
        agencyName=agenName;
        final typee=launch['launch_service_provider']['type'];
        type=typee;
        final r_name=launch['rocket']['configuration']['name'];
        rocketName=r_name;
        final r_variant=launch['rocket']['configuration']['variant'];
        rocketVariant=r_variant;
        final m_name=launch['mission']['name'];
        missionName=m_name;
        final orbit_name=launch['mission']['orbit']['name'];
        orbitName=orbit_name;
        final pad_location=launch['pad']['location']['name'];
        location=pad_location;
        final estimated_time=launch['net'];
        time=estimated_time;
        // final estimated_date=launch['pad']['location']['name'];
        // date=estimated_date;
        setState(() {});
      } else {
        print('No upcoming launches found');
      }
    } else {
      print('Failed to fetch upcoming launches: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }

  void updateCountdown() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final now = DateTime.now().toLocal();
    final duration = launchTime.difference(now);
    final days = duration.inDays;
    final hours = duration.inHours.remainder(24);
    final minutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60);
    final seconds = duration.inSeconds.remainder(60);
    final final_time = time.split("T");
    final date_final = final_time.elementAt(0).toString();
    final time_final = final_time.elementAt(1).toString();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      drawer: Nav_Drawer(),

      appBar: AppBar(

        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text('Welcome'),
      ),
      body:
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              'Next Launch in:',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 24),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),

            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                CarouselSlider(
                    items: [
                      Image.network('https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/559/511/583/spacex-rocket-falcon-9-smoke-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                      Image.network('https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/81/233/257/spacex-rocket-smoke-cape-canaveral-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                      Image.network('https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/758/798/536/spacex-rocket-launch-pads-falcon-heavy-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                      Image.network('https://cdnn1.img.sputniknews.com/img/07e6/0a/17/1102543952_0:0:3071:1728_1920x0_80_0_0_94bf3eb33e85402d96a49a4e84e93b84.jpg'),
                      Image.network('https://static.theprint.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/6-01-e1530068959485.jpg?compress=true&quality=80&w=376&dpr=2.6'),
                      Image.network('https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/390/31/781/spacex-rocket-falcon-9-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                    ],
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    height: 300,
                    // height: 200.0,
                    // enlargeCenterPage: true,
                    autoPlay: false,
                    enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                    autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                    viewportFraction: 1,
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '$days : $hours : $minutes : $seconds',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 30,
                        color: Colors.white
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                        'Days : Hours : Minutes : Seconds',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 12
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

              ],
            ),
            Text(Name,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20
            ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
              Text('Description:',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      fontSize: 14
                  ),
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 4),
              Text(description,
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 14
                ),),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Agency:',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                      ),
                      ),
                      Text(agencyName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Launch type:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(type,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Rocket name:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(rocketName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Rocket variant:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(rocketVariant,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Mission Name:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(missionName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Orbit:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(orbitName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Launch Location:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      ],
                  ),
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                        children:[
                      Text(location,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                          Divider(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Date:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(date_final,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Time:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(time_final,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  ],
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(0),
    );
  }
}
```

I think putting a circular progress Indicator till the page loads might solve it but not sure how to implement it correctly as I don't know which condition to check.
Maybe it has something to do with the fact that it is trying to access some properties before they are loaded and hence the problem might be solved by checking if 'results' is empty or not. But can't do that because its scope is limited to the 'fetchMyHome()' function. I am relatively new to flutter so please help.

Comment: Did you try using a `FutureBuilder` widget? I think it might help as the data on your page totally depends on the `fetchMyHome()` function, which is a `Future`. This will also eliminate the need for global variables to store the data.

Comment: And how exactly we can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the quick fix, I introduced two variables `loading` and `error`.

Here is my code for a state `_MyHomeState`

```dart
class _MyHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  bool loading = true;//introduced for loading
  String? error;//introduced for handling error case
  DateTime launchTime = DateTime.now();
  String Name = '';
  String description = '';
  String agencyName = '';
  String type = '';
  String rocketName = '';
  String rocketVariant = '';
  String missionName = '';
  String orbitName = '';
  String location = '';
  String time = '';
  String date = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchMyHome();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => updateCountdown());
  }

  void fetchMyHome() async {
    final response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse('https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.2.0/launch/upcoming/')
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      final List<dynamic> results = data['results'];
      if (results.isNotEmpty) {
        final launch = results.elementAt(0);
        final launchTimeStr = launch['net'];
        launchTime = DateTime.parse(launchTimeStr).toLocal();
        final Launchname = launch['name'];
        Name = Launchname.toString();
        final descp = launch['mission']['description'];
        description = descp;
        final agenName = launch['launch_service_provider']['name'];
        agencyName = agenName;
        final typee = launch['launch_service_provider']['type'];
        type = typee;
        final r_name = launch['rocket']['configuration']['name'];
        rocketName = r_name;
        final r_variant = launch['rocket']['configuration']['variant'];
        rocketVariant = r_variant;
        final m_name = launch['mission']['name'];
        missionName = m_name;
        final orbit_name = launch['mission']['orbit']['name'];
        orbitName = orbit_name;
        final pad_location = launch['pad']['location']['name'];
        location = pad_location;
        final estimated_time = launch['net'];
        time = estimated_time;
        // final estimated_date=launch['pad']['location']['name'];
        // date=estimated_date;
      } else {
        error = 'No upcoming launches found';
        print('No upcoming launches found');
      }
    } else {
      error = 'Failed to fetch upcoming launches';
      print('Failed to fetch upcoming launches: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
    loading = false;
    setState(() {});
  }

  void updateCountdown() {
    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (loading) {
      return const Scaffold(body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),),);
    }
    if (error != null) {
      return Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text(error!),),);
    }
    final now = DateTime.now().toLocal();
    final duration = launchTime.difference(now);
    final days = duration.inDays;
    final hours = duration.inHours.remainder(24);
    final minutes = duration.inMinutes.remainder(60);
    final seconds = duration.inSeconds.remainder(60);
    final final_time = time.split("T");
    final date_final = final_time.elementAt(0).toString();
    final time_final = final_time.elementAt(1).toString();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
      drawer: Nav_Drawer(),

      appBar: AppBar(

        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        title: const Text('Welcome'),
      ),
      body:
      SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(

          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text(
              'Next Launch in:',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 24),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 20),

            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                CarouselSlider(
                  items: [
                    Image.network(
                        'https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/559/511/583/spacex-rocket-falcon-9-smoke-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                    Image.network(
                        'https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/81/233/257/spacex-rocket-smoke-cape-canaveral-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                    Image.network(
                        'https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/758/798/536/spacex-rocket-launch-pads-falcon-heavy-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                    Image.network(
                        'https://cdnn1.img.sputniknews.com/img/07e6/0a/17/1102543952_0:0:3071:1728_1920x0_80_0_0_94bf3eb33e85402d96a49a4e84e93b84.jpg'),
                    Image.network(
                        'https://static.theprint.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/6-01-e1530068959485.jpg?compress=true&quality=80&w=376&dpr=2.6'),
                    Image.network(
                        'https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/390/31/781/spacex-rocket-falcon-9-wallpaper-preview.jpg'),
                  ],
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    height: 300,
                    // height: 200.0,
                    // enlargeCenterPage: true,
                    autoPlay: false,
                    enableInfiniteScroll: true,
                    autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(seconds: 3),
                    viewportFraction: 1,
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      '$days : $hours : $minutes : $seconds',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 30,
                          color: Colors.white
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Days : Hours : Minutes : Seconds',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 12
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

              ],
            ),
            Text(Name,
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: 20
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Text('Description:',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        fontSize: 14
                    ),
                  ),

                  SizedBox(height: 4),
                  Text(description,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14
                    ),),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Agency:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(agencyName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Launch type:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(type,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Rocket name:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(rocketName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Rocket variant:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(rocketVariant,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Mission Name:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(missionName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Orbit:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(orbitName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Launch Location:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      Text(location,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                      Divider(
                        color: Colors.white,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Date:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(date_final,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Divider(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text('Time:',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.blueAccent,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(time_final,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavBar(0),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Error occurs when you are trying to access the index value in the list which does not exist:

**For example:**

```dart
List list = ["a","b"];
list[4]; // <-- Range Error since there's no element at index 4 in the list,

our application tries to use value at index 4, which does not exist. 

**Solution:**

 Try to debug at a point where you are using the index value of a list.
```

Comment: That value does not exist initially but as the data loads that value will automatically come. How can put an interval of approx 5 seconds before it tries to fetch the value so that until then the screen loads??

Comment: why are you not using future builder?

Answer (score 0):

The Error occurs when you are trying to access the index value in the list which does not exist:

**For example:**

```
List list = ["a","b"];
list[4]; // <-- Range Error since there's no element at index 4 in the list,
```

our application tries to use value at index 4, which does not exist.

**Solution**: Try to debug at a point where you are using the index value of a list.

If you are fetching data from and API that's the correct way of doing it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: MyStatefulWidget(),
    );
  }
}



class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  Future fetchResult() async {
final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://lldev.thespacedevs.com/2.2.0/launch/upcoming/');

if(response.statusCode == 200){
 final apiData = jsonDecode(response.body);
     
    return apiData;

}else{
   return null;
}

}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTextStyle(
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.displayMedium!,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchResult(), // a previously-obtained Future<String> or null
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          List<Widget> children;
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
           final List<dynamic> results = snapshot.data['results'];
 return  ListView.builder(
             itemCount: results.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
              color: Colors.red,
            );
            },
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            children = <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.error_outline,
                color: Colors.red,
                size: 60,
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              ),
            ];
          } else {
            children = const <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
              ),
            ];
          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: children,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```